# Dot product is an Euclidean norm in Euclidean space?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I might be missing something, but from what I have learned in linear algebra, for a matrix or vector multiplication to be valid you need to have number of columns in pre-multiplying vector to be the same as the number of rows of the multiplies one, i.e. in $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$, $\vec{a}$ should have the number of columns that is equal to the number of rows in $\vec{b}$.

Yet Euclidean norm is defined as:

$$||x|| := \sqrt{x \cdot x}$$

suppose $x$ is a $2$ by $1$ vector. Then you would be multiplying 2 by 1 vector by 2 by 1 vecotr, which is undefined. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of dot product of $n\times 1$ real matrices:

$$x\cdot y \stackrel{def}= x^Ty$$

Comment: follow up question then. Suppose that $\Delta C \approx \triangledown C \cdot \Delta v$, (i.e. change in some function C is gradient of C multiplied by some change in v (parameter vector of C, that we are free to choose). And now we select $\Delta v = \triangledown C$, so we have $\Delta C \approx \triangledown C \cdot \triangledown C$. Now why is this multiplication a dot product? (as opposed to usual multiplication)

Comment: I am referring to this: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html, below equation number 10

Comment: $\nabla C\cdot \Delta v$ is the matrix representation of the derivative of the function $C$ at some unspecified point evaluated at $\Delta v$ -- i.e. the matrix rep of $DC_x(\Delta v)$.  So it's unclear to me how you could plug in $\nabla C$ for $\Delta v$.  But either way, $\nabla C\cdot \Delta v$ **and** $\nabla C\cdot \nabla C$ would be dot products.

Comment: I think I got it. $\Delta C \approx (\triangledown C)^T \Delta v = (\triangledown C)^T \triangledown C = \triangledown C \cdot \triangledown C = ||\triangledown C||^2$

Comment: That's what they're claiming, yes.  I'm a little dubious on their math, but nonetheless $v\mapsto v' = v-\eta\nabla C$ *is* the way to iterate your points in the steepest descent algorithm.  So they seem to get the correct answer.

Comment: The explanations of how the neural networks work before all the math are quite great, however. Thanks for your help